# Google text to speech

Tags: python, text-to-speech, google-translate

When I am trying to access this URL:

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello

It is showing a captcha page and saying

> This page appears when Google automatically detects requests coming from your computer network which appear to be in violation of the google policies.

Can anyone tell me the solution of this problem.

Answer (score -2):

As you said, it's a violation of the Google policies.

Comment: it is saying 'Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. ' also.

Comment: Seriously, if Google ask you to perform human checking, it is because they expect you to use it with their product.

Comment: Ok..Have you any idea about text to speech?

Comment: there isn't API for this service exept translation only here : https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs

Comment: but that api is only for translation :(..anyway thanks @jitrixis